# function to count character from hashing result

Tags: string, char, operands

what is wrong with this code:

this the hole sintax:

> import bcrypt
> import hashlib
> import time
> import string
>
> Sample password
> password = "mySecretP@ss"
>
> def bcrypt_hash(password):
> salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
> return bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode(), salt)
>
> def md5_hash(password):
> return hashlib.md5(password.encode()).hexdigest()
>
> def sha1_hash(password):
> return hashlib.sha1(password.encode()).hexdigest()
>
> def count_characters_and_punctuation(text):
> num_characters = len(text)
> num_punctuation = sum(1 for   char in text if char in string.punctuation)
> return num_characters, num_punctuation
>
> def main():
> start_time = time.time()
> bcrypt_result = bcrypt_hash(password)
> bcrypt_time = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000  # Convert to milliseconds
>
> start_time = time.time()
> md5_result = md5_hash(password)
> md5_time = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000
>
> start_time = time.time()
> sha1_result = sha1_hash(password)
> sha1_time = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000
>
> print(f"Password: {password}")
> print(f"BCrypt Hash: {bcrypt_result}")
> print(f"MD5 Hash: {md5_result}")
> print(f"SHA-1 Hash: {sha1_result}")
>
> print(f"Time taken for BCrypt: {bcrypt_time:.6f} ms")
> print(f"Time taken for MD5: {md5_time:.6f} ms")
> print(f"Time taken for SHA-1: {sha1_time:.6f} ms")
>
> bcrypt_char_count, bcrypt_punctuation_count = count_characters_and_punctuation(bcrypt_result)
> md5_char_count, md5_punctuation_count = count_characters_and_punctuation(md5_result)
> sha1_char_count, sha1_punctuation_count = count_characters_and_punctuation(sha1_result)
>
> print(f"BCrypt: Character Count: {bcrypt_char_count}, Punctuation Count: {bcrypt_punctuation_count}")
> print(f"MD5: Character Count: {md5_char_count}, Punctuation Count: {md5_punctuation_count}")
> print(f"SHA-1: Character Count: {sha1_char_count}, Punctuation Count: {sha1_punctuation_count}")
>
> if **name** == "**main**":
> main()

20     num_characters = len(text)
---> 21     num_punctuation = sum(1 for   char in text if char in string.punctuation)
22     return num_characters, num_punctuation
23

TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not int